# Form with top labels works but not with side labels

Tags: css, css-grid

This works:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-areas: 
  "contact comments"
  "... button";*/
  grid-template-rows: 12em;
  grid-template-columns: 12em;
  grid-gap: .8em;
  background: yellow; // for debugging
  padding: 0;
}

.lp {
  // label properties
  padding: 0.4em; //1.1em
  background-color: cyan;
}

.ip {
  // input properties
  padding: 0.4em; //1.1em
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

// maps areas to markup elements
.lnam { grid-area: 1/1; } // label Name area -> label elem
.inam { grid-area: 2/1; } // input Name area -> input elem 
.leml { grid-area: 3/1; } // ditto for Email
.ieml { grid-area: 4/1; }

.ltel { grid-area: 5 / 1; } // and Telephone

.itel { grid-area: 6/1; }
```

```html
<form class="parent">
  <div>
    <label class="lp lnam" for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="ip inam" type="text" id="name" required>
    <label class="lp leml" for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="ip ieml" type="text" id="email" required>
    <label class="lp ltel" for="tph">Phone</label>
    <input class="ip itel" type="text" id="tph" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

but could not get side `label`s to work. The `input` element is placed below the label, but it should follow the `label` on the same row.
The code below is nearly the same as the code that is working above with identical markup.
Differences:  `grid-area` specs and `grid-template-columns` (two columns for side `label`s)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-areas: 
  "contact comments"
  "... button";*/
  grid-template-rows: 4em;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 200px;
  grid-gap: .8em;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0;
}

.lp {
  padding: 0.4em; //1.1em
  //border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.ip {
  padding: 0.4em; //1.1em
  //border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.lnam {
  grid-area: 1/1 /2/2;
} // area -> element

.inam {
  grid-area: 1/2 /2/3;
}

/* .leml { grid-area: 3/11; }
.ieml { grid-area: 4/1; }
.ltel { grid-area: 5/1; }
.itel { grid-area: 6/1; } */
```

```html
<form class="parent">
  <div>
    <label class="lp lnam" for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="ip inam" type="text" id="name" required>
    <!--<label class="lp leml" for="email">Email</label>
<input class="ip ieml" type="text" id="email" required>
<label class="lp ltel" for="tph">Phone</label>
<input class="ip itel" type="text" id="tph" required>-->
  </div>
</form>
```

I used both Firefox and Chrome and got identical results.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remember that grid items are only direct children of grid container, not all descendants. So changed selector `.parent` to `parent > div` to make it work and removed `grid-area` properties because grid items will align automatically even without this properties.

I assume you want label column to take width by content and textboxes to take all remaining width. Also I think that you don't want your grid tracks to be `12em` height. So I changed `grid-template-columns` and removed `grid-temaplate-rows`.

Demo of result:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent > div {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-areas: 
  "contact comments"
  "... button";*/
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: .8em;
  background: yellow; // for debugging
  padding: 0;
}

.lp {
  // label properties
  padding: 0.4em; //1.1em
  background-color: cyan;
}

.ip {
  // input properties
  padding: 0.4em; //1.1em
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<form class="parent">
  <div>
    <label class="lp lnam" for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="ip inam" type="text" id="name" required>
    <label class="lp leml" for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="ip ieml" type="text" id="email" required>
    <label class="lp ltel" for="tph">Phone</label>
    <input class="ip itel" type="text" id="tph" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, the div-element below the form opening tag is the troublemaker. As you suggested changing the selector solves the problem. Removing the div tags or moving the class spec from the form tag to the div tag also solve the side-label problem. Removing the grid-area settings reduces the solution to almost nothing. Nice!
Is there also a nice short solution for setting a top-label above the input element? Would like to know how?

Comment: @resander If I understood your last questions correctly you just need one column so you can change `grid-template-columns` to `grid-template-columns: 1fr`.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I am new to css grid and css flexbox. I read the documentation about auto-flow yesterday, but did not see relevance of it then. Now I realise it is very convenient for making regular forms.

Comment: @resander Glad to help you.